# How do we 'execute' or 'do'? A concise word to "carry out this defined task in a specific context" so we get done?

Tags: single-word-requests

In English one symbol that is overloaded in computer terminology is 'execute'. Another less harsh sounding directive 'do'. I 'do' sounds like a contract, 'execute' like a sentence.

In the 'do' case we may delimit its applicable context with 'done'.

A third but ambiguous context delineating technique is to use the couch phase 'begin' followed later by 'end'. This is more for context scope than to act as an imperative exhortation.

Is there a better English verb we could use to instruct our equipment on how to behave?

Comment: Hi Georgey. I'm a bit confused by your question. It starts out sounding like a request for advice on natural language, that is for words to use in conversation or correspondence with your colleagues or customers, but then you seem to be talking about delineating a block of code with Begin and End and asking how you can better instruct your equipment on how to behave. Unless you're using some form of AI-driven equipment controlled by natural language algorithms the syntax of the programming language constrains what you type. Cliches and repetition don't bother machines, only humans.

Comment: The delimiting of context with 'done' or 'enddo', 'end', 'stop', etc are for reference and not meant to limit the need for me to find a simpler, less harsh imperative for direction to move along or carry out a task. A word like 'perform' is associated with sports and art and speak of a higher level of achievement and being. I'll take that. My days of 'executing' can now end with the death of that phrase in my vocabulary.